# how do i fire elmah logger after Application_Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, logging, elmah, application-error

I'm small mechanism that analyse **404 errors**

i have small xml that contain old urls and redirect it to new

im doing it in **Application_Error** but i see that **elmah** log error first and the fire **Application_Error**, it mean that if old url will be found in xml **elmah** will log error anyway :(

is it possible to somehow fix it?

thanks

Comment: looks like i need to use kind of filter: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering